# Evolution not showing latest email in my IMAP inbox

Tags: evolution, imap

I've got an IMAP mail server running dovecot.

I use several different mail clients -- K-9 mail on my Nexus One, and RoundCube Webmail when I'm not on my main computer.

On my main computer, I use Evolution. However, it doesn't show the latest emails on the server. I can see them with other clients; just not Evolution.

Is there a way to force Evolution to re-load the entire folder?

Answer (score 7):

There are several settings for an IMAP account you can make in Evolution. On first startup, or when you create a new account, or in case you already have an account by selecting *Edit -> Preferences -> Mail Accounts -> account@provider -> Edit -> Receiving Options* you will be presented the following options:

[image]

The settings given here make sure that **all** mails are displayed in Evolution. As soon as you check only subscribed folders, start to apply filters, or check for junk mails you risk that only part of your mails are displayed.

Only if there is no success with settings then as a last resort you may have to delete the local IMAP folder to force reloading as has [already been suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29138/evolution-not-showing-latest-email-in-my-imap-inbox/29550#29550).

Answer (score 4):

To force evolution to reload the entire IMAP account is to delete the IMAP folder in the hidden evolution folder in your home folder while evolution is closed.

[image: IMAP folder]

Alternatively if you have multiple IMAP accounts you can go in to the IMAP folder and delete the folder pertaining to that account.

[image: IMAP Account folder]

This will force evolution to reload the entire account.

Hope this helps.

---

**edit**

It sounds as though the account has been set-up as a standard IMAP account as a posed to an IMAP+ account. What's the difference I here you say (because if your here you will need to know).

IMAP+ in Evolution is an [IMAP IDLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP_IDLE) enabled account which means that the client can tell the server to immediately sync all mail meaning that manual or automatic periodic syncing are obsolete.

With this type of account you should see the email as soon as it has arrived with your server.

Due to a bug that is now fixed in 2.32 (the standard version in 10.10 is 2.30.3) you need to check the "Use idle if the server supports it" option in the options tab.

Comment: My folders where not as pictured but in `.cache/evolution/mail`

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with Ubuntu 19.04 and Evolution 3.321.-12 using sustem online accounts. After removing local computer account from Evolution, it started to work.