# Evolution with Office365 account (EWS) fails to automatically send

Tags: email, evolution, office365

Installed Ubuntu MATE 16.04 and configured evolution (v3.18.5.2) to talk to my Office365 mail/calendar account.

The issue is with sending an email. I press the send button after composing (or replying) and the email is queued to the Outbox, but it never leaves, even after multiple checks for new mail  I have to manually do a Send/Receive to flush the email out to the Office365 server.

Let me clarify further:  I am using Evolution-EWS (Exchange Web Services), not IMAP or POP. I have tried to determine what is happening by running evolution from the command line: EWS_DEBUG=2 evolution.  However, I don't see any logging after hitting the SEND button in the compose window. Nothing occurs (unless I receive email) until I press the RECEIVE/SEND ALL button.

I have the following packages installed -

pmahan@Chaos-~ 7> `sudo apt list | grep evolution | grep installed`

```
evolution/xenial-updates,now 3.18.5.2-0ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed]       
evolution-common/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 3.18.5.2-0ubuntu3.1 all [installed,automatic] 
evolution-data-server/xenial,now 3.18.5-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic] 
evolution-data-server-common/xenial,xenial,now 3.18.5-1ubuntu1 all [installed] 
evolution-data-server-online-accounts/xenial,now 3.18.5-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic] 
evolution-ews/xenial,now 3.18.5-1 amd64 [installed] 
evolution-plugins/xenial-updates,now 3.18.5.2-0ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed] 
evolution-plugins-experimental/xenial-updates,now 3.18.5.2-0ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed] 
libevolution/xenial-updates,now 3.18.5.2-0ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

I'm frankly stumped at what to look at.

Comment: What steps have you already taken ?

Comment: Check the settings before anything else, namely SSL: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/POP-and-IMAP-settings-for-Outlook-Office-365-for-business-7fc677eb-2491-4cbc-8153-8e7113525f6c

Comment: Have you seen [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29138/evolution-not-showing-latest-email-in-my-imap-inbox)

Comment: Edit to clarify what I need help on

Comment: Sorry for not getting back, but this began working about 9 months ago.  At some point, an automatic software update occurred and the problem went away.  So something was fixed, just not sure what was fixed.